# Android Firebase: Microsoft Authentication Failure

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Where I got my Client ID [image: Where I got my Client ID] Where I got my Client Secret [image: Where I got my Client Secret] [image: Firebase Console - Microsoft] I've been trying to use Firebase Authentication in my app with Microsoft as a provider using the [Firebase Docs on how to authenticate with Microsoft](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/microsoft-oauth). But I've come with an error in Logcat saying:

```
The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Error getting 
verification code from microsoft.com response: 
error=invalid_request&error_description=AADSTS9002331:%20Application%20'8749ccd1-9dea- 
4920-a0fd- 72fffdcf2b38'(AppName)%20is%20configured%20for%20use%20by%20Microsoft%20Account%20users%20only.%20Please%20use%20the%20/consumers%20endpoint%20to%20serve%20this%20request.%0D%0ATrace%20ID:%20ba459e48-3fd1-4bd4-aa88-d878701b2d02%0D%0ACorrelation%20ID:%208157e86e-8acf-459f-9f18-07734bc971bb%0D%0ATimestamp:%202021-07-20%2019:56:47Z&state=AMbdmDmMtw9NcT5fPjPkiW7M0l70V9s86Tfhc5CVrSZYKpR1Dqw3PL8LrBYVT4zU26o-J2_ydtdFjRkwI074fWaWRO6J1KDc3b2xyT9wDilWZc13d52RgdIb6dGQRXllvdlzr1yDG3pMKzDofxRGxgCXVV_psklIoKsJ159ltFoacD-ezVsqKFnEJ89jdGCwoH3ijJ4eG1DovqbfbhfQu4kZ7IFqOnvHRHVrIC4ctO05K1HJ0mUjo1yUpT6ai383xajYdK3l767FkyU4JOG5M9yD0KBULxIwoZpvXqAG8bkgEf4ht3ugiCnceooKTA7IcipK3mwuyFrQ0OkHGZVOzP3czo-NzuKMZp6uQm5ewjczf8X3hBYUGfrk70qr2b7w_gFg5xkkPEE6drQJAyMOfY-H-rM1EJqtsWehRIvhHcFjwy2c0SGBxsH1U-HLUktCfx8&providerId=microsoft.com ]
```

This is my MicrosoftAccountActivity:

```
package com.avs.auth;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.OAuthProvider;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MicrosoftAccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private Button microsoftLoginButton;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    private OAuthProvider.Builder builder;
    private OAuthProvider provider;
    private Task<AuthResult> pendingResultTask;
    private UpdateUI updateUI;
    private Intent intent;
    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    public static final String TAG = "MicrosoftAuth";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_microsoft_account);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        microsoftLoginButton = findViewById(R.id.microsoftLoginButton);

        microsoftLoginButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            builder = OAuthProvider.newBuilder("microsoft.com");
            builder.addCustomParameter("prompt", "consent");
            builder.addCustomParameter("login_hint", "");
            builder.addCustomParameter("tenant", getString(R.string.microsoft_tenant_id));

            arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
            arrayList.add("user.read");
            arrayList.add("email.read");

            builder.setScopes(arrayList);

            provider = builder.build();

            microsoftSignIn();
        }
    };

    private void microsoftSignIn() {
        pendingResultTask = firebaseAuth.getPendingAuthResult();
        if (pendingResultTask != null) {
            pendingResultTask.addOnSuccessListener(taskOnSuccessListener).addOnFailureListener(taskOnFailureListener);
        } else {
            firebaseAuth.startActivityForSignInWithProvider(this, provider)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(providerOnSuccessListener).addOnFailureListener(providerOnFailureListener);
        }
    }

    private OnSuccessListener<AuthResult> taskOnSuccessListener = new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Creation Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    private OnFailureListener taskOnFailureListener = new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Creation Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    private OnSuccessListener<AuthResult> providerOnSuccessListener = new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            updateUI = UpdateUI.updateUI(firebaseUser, TAG, firebaseUser.getDisplayName());
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };

    private OnFailureListener providerOnFailureListener = new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            updateUI = UpdateUI.updateUI(null, TAG, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Creation Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

If you ask me why everything is private, it's because it was the solution to one of my other auth provider errors (Google).

Anyway, this is my UpdateUI class:

```
package com.avs.auth;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class UpdateUI {

    public static void updateUI(FirebaseUser user, String TAG, String userName){
        if (user != null){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("DATA", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("NAME", userName);
            editor.apply();
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Try again");
        }
    }
}
```

I've seen solutions for iOS and Web but I'm using Android.

How can I fix this?

If you need other details, please don't hesitate to comment.

Answer (score 0):

I was fancing the same issue.

You need to paste into Firebase Application Secret the value under **Value** column of the token generated, **not** the value under **Secret Id** column:
[image]

So you could generate a new one if you are not able to see yours.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,  but I'm sorry to say that it did not work.